# How far will a 1Hz EM Wave propagate if it's source oscillator is running for exactly one second?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

If you have an Oscillator set on 1Hz and you let it run for exactly one second
connected to an Antenna , how far will the generated EM Wave travel ?

Comment: Well how far do you think it will have traveled?

Comment: I thought it would go as far as one wavelength since there was only one Hertz running for one second

Comment: It's an EM wave: $d=ct$

Comment: @BillN Regardless of the wavelength ??

Comment: $\lambda = c/f$.  Yes, regardless of wavelength.  Your oscillator is controlling the frequency. The speed is $c$. Once the E-field begins oscillating in the antenna, the energy released goes and goes.

Comment: But from zero to $ct$ the energy decreases as described in the Answer below ?

Comment: Take some time to think about and understand what we've said already. The wave doesn't stop simply because the source stops.  Think about what happens with an echo or a radar signal. Radar is pulsed. On/off. Done.

Comment: Yes, i understood that only after @zeldredge answered, but then from $d=ct$ it can be concluded that one cycle of one Hertz for one second would make $t=1$ and so after a distance of $c$ the wave will no longer exist and that would mean that it was decaying through the distance it passed, so i wanted to make sure i got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EM waves don't "stop" they just slowly become weaker as $r^{-2}$, so one could conceivably answer "forever." On the other hand, the wave will quickly become so dissipated/spread out that there isn't much to measure, so you have a practical limit where it won't be detectable. However if this is your intent, you haven't given us enough information to answer the question, because we would need to know the power of the transmitter. A 1Hz wave could be very strong or very weak; the frequency is independent of the amplitude. The frequency-time stuff you've given doesn't really apply to the question of how far out the wave can be detected, for that we need to know transmitter power.

Comment: But unlike sound\water waves which propagate the disturbance throughout the medium , i thought EM Waves are being pushed because the source keeps creating more and more changing electric fields, so you are saying one oscillation is enough to 'push' a wave outwards ? until it like you say, get weaker and weaker ?

Comment: The wave doesn't have to get pushed. It's a traveling wave. You make a disturbance (changing electric fields), and then the region around you in space generates a changing electric field in response, and then the next region outward generates a changing electric field in response to the previous region, etc, etc.

Comment: I guess all the animations i've seen for this never showed a single cycle traveling alone, so i had this notion of it being pushed.

Comment: It should be noted that if you have an impulse like that, you can't really say it's a "1Hz" wave. You won't have a pure spectrum, you'll get something a little more like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet

Comment: Is there an animation you think best describes all the vectors around the EM wave ? , i mean one that goes through most of the angles around the source in 3D

Comment: How does what you said about it getting weaker and weaker until there isn't much to measure , go with $d=ct$ ? or does the $d$ symbolize the measurable distance ?

Comment: @soundslikefiziks I don't have an animation of it, sorry. The $d = ct$ formula doesn't have anything to do with how far a wave *can* travel, it just tells you how far a wave *has* traveled after a time $t$. It's just $d = vt$ with the speed of electromagnetic waves put in.